# Running multiple versions of the same app for comparison's sake

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is it possible to keep different versions of my app on my iphone? Currently, I always have the latest version of my app on my phone. But what if I’d like to run older versions of the app from time to time to see if the changes I’ve made are actually improvements.

Should I revert to an older version of my code and deploy it to my device? Or is it better to make multiple targets? I'd like to easily compare several versions of my app on my iphone, if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way using XCode to install multiple builds of the same iOS app to your iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139987/whats-the-best-way-using-xcode-to-install-multiple-builds-of-the-same-ios-app-t)